# Why does npm disappear and node -v command show different version against nvm ls?

Tags: node.js, npm

I tried to use npm to install some packages,and command line prompt `npm: command not found`(which I have installed for sure), I use `node -v` checked my node version ,it's `v12.19.0`,then I check my nvm using `nvm ls`,it shows:

```
bogon:es6-tutorial zhangyifan$ nvm ls
        v16.4.0
->       system
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v16.4.0) (default)
stable -> 16.4 (-> v16.4.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/fermium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.1 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.17.1 (-> N/A)
```

How did this happen？What should I do next to install node and npm correctly?

(supplement info:I found npm lost earlier this afternoon,which version should be v12.19.0,so I used nvm to reinstall node and get the latest version v16.4.0,I checked the version of node and npm at that time,they were all v16.4.0 )

Comment: what is the output of `which node`? Probably you have some node installation from your package manager which messed up your nvm installation.

Comment: @derpirscher I use homebrew to install node v12.19.0 long ago，but It worked well all the time  until today

Comment: Well obviously something changed in your system (or even just in a specific environment)  where the PATH is not correctly set, so that `node` and `npm` executables are either not in the PATH at all, or at least are in the PATH after the `node` executable installed with homebrew. When `node --version` returns `12.9`, this is the first `node` executable to be found in the path ..

Answer (score 0):

Use this command. It will install node 12.
`nvm install lts/erbium`
`nvm use lts/erbium`

Comment: My goal is not get node 12 back,I just want node and npm installed stably and do not  disappear any more...